# How can I search for a value that's repeated in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I have a spreedsheet (Sheet2) that has 4 columns:

```
ID | Name | Semester | SemesterAvg | Overall Avg | Period |
1  | John |    1     |      2.5    |     2.5     | 20132  |
1  | John |    2     |      3.5    |      3      | 20141  |
1  | John |    3     |       4     |     3.3     | 20142  |
2  | Maria|    1     |      3.2    |     3.2     | 20132  |
3  | Beth |    1     |      3.8    |     3.8     | 20141  |
```

And I have another spreadsheet (Sheet1) that has 5 columns:

```
ID | Name | Note 1S | Note 2S | Note 3S | LastestAVG |
1  | John |         |         |         |            |
2  | Maria|         |         |         |            |
3  | Beth |         |         |         |            |
```

The "Note 1S" column contains notes for the 1st semester, "Note 2S" for the 2nd semester, and "Note 3S" for the 3rd semester. "Overall Avg" contains the average of all semesters up to that point.

How can I bring the most recent OverallAvg from Sheet2 into the column LastestAVG in Sheet1?

Comment: How is the `Period` column formatted? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: As a number, I just edited the column form 2013-1 to 20131.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the cell under "LatestAVG" on Sheet1 to show an average of all of the value in the "SemersterAvg" column. If that is the case, insert the following formula under "LatestAVG" in Sheet1:

> =AVERAGE(Sheet2!D:D)

This formula assumes that the tables above begin in cell A1 of both sheets.

Comment: No, I want it to show the Sheet2-Overall Avg depending on the highest Period. Your formula works but have in mind that there may be more students and the Overall Avg is depending on the Period which was generated.

Comment: Okay. I think I understand what you are looking for now. I don't think that the VLOOKUP function will be useful in this case. That function requires that the index data (Sheet2, in this case) is sorted highest to lowest, by the left most column. It looks like Sheet2 is sorted first by the students' names, then by the period. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, that is the case. Is there another way than ordering Sheet2?